# svg рамки в html

Tags: html, css, svg

Как исправить, svg рамки, чтобы текст был внутри rect? Сейчас рамки находятся под текстом

```css
.menu-item
{
  padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
}
.menu-item svg
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
}
.menu-item svg rect{
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 200px 70px 200px 70px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .9s all;
}
@keyframes menuanim
{

}
.wrapper
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top:20%;
}
.title
{
  width: 43ch;
  color:black;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 40px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 4px solid orange;
  animation: flashing-border 0.75s step-end infinite, printed-text 7s steps(43);
}
@keyframes flashing-border
{
  0%
  {
    border-color: orange;
  }
  50%
  {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  100%
  {
    border-color: orange;
  }
}
@keyframes printed-text
{
  from
  {
    width: 0;
  }
}
.wrapper1{
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.btn{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper1 svg{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper1 svg rect{
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 10px 180px 20px 50px 20px 180px 20px 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .9s all;
}


.btn:hover rect{
  stroke-dasharray: 200px 0 70px 0 200px 0 70px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Веб-студия BondWeb</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top:30px;">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div style="background:black;border-radius:100px;width:100px;height:100px;" class="text-center justify-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand" style="font-size:50px;font-family:monospace;color:black;padding-left:10px;padding-top:10px;">
          BW
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu" style="display:inline-block;padding-right:20px;">
      <ul>
        <li style="display:inline-block;color:black;font-size:25px;" class="menu-item">Услуги
        <svg>
          <rect></rect>
        </svg>
        </li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;color:black;font-size:25px;" class="menu-item">Стоимость
          <svg>
            <rect></rect>
          </svg>
        </li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;color:black;font-size:25px;" class="menu-item">Контакты
          <svg>
            <rect></rect>
          </svg>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1 class="title">Текст - текст текст текст текст текст текст</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper1">
  <a href="" class="btn">Заказать
    <svg>
      <rect></rect>
    </svg>
  </a>
</div>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: А зачем там вообще SVG? border чем не угодил?

Comment: лучше поместить текст внутрь svg, если вам угодно именно svg рамки

Comment: @DaemonHK далее буду делать анимацию, а svg  это приятнее

Comment: @StrangerintheQ при помещении в svg текст пропадает, как это можно исправить?

Comment: @Alexander это другой вопрос, просто он там немного по-другому устроен

Comment: @StrangerintheQ подскажите, пожалуйста как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно вставить текст сразу в svg

```
<text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">Стоимость</text>
```

`x="50%" y="50%"` устанавливают точку привязки

`text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle"` ровняют его по центру относительно точки привязки

Вот Ваш фрагмент кода, с моими изменениями

```css
.menu-item
{
  padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
}
.menu-item svg
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
}
.menu-item svg rect{
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 200px 70px 200px 70px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .9s all;
}
@keyframes menuanim
{

}
.wrapper
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top:20%;
}
.title
{
  width: 43ch;
  color:black;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 40px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 4px solid orange;
  animation: flashing-border 0.75s step-end infinite, printed-text 7s steps(43);
}
@keyframes flashing-border
{
  0%
  {
    border-color: orange;
  }
  50%
  {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  100%
  {
    border-color: orange;
  }
}
@keyframes printed-text
{
  from
  {
    width: 0;
  }
}
.wrapper1{
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.btn{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper1 svg{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper1 svg rect{
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 10px 180px 20px 50px 20px 180px 20px 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .9s all;
}


.btn:hover rect{
  stroke-dasharray: 200px 0 70px 0 200px 0 70px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Веб-студия BondWeb</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top:30px;">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div style="background:black;border-radius:100px;width:100px;height:100px;" class="text-center justify-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand" style="font-size:50px;font-family:monospace;color:black;padding-left:10px;padding-top:10px;">
          BW
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu" style="display:inline-block;padding-right:20px;">
      <ul>
        <li style="display:inline-block;color:black;font-size:25px;" class="menu-item">
        <svg>
          <text fill="rgba(123,123,11,0.7)" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">Услуги</text>
          <rect></rect>
        </svg>
        </li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;color:black;font-size:25px;" class="menu-item">
          <svg>
            <text stroke="red" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">Стоимость</text>
            <rect></rect>
          </svg>
        </li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;color:black;font-size:25px;" class="menu-item">
          <svg>
            <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">Контакты</text> 
            <rect></rect>
          </svg>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1 class="title">Текст - текст текст текст текст текст текст</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper1">
  <a href="" class="btn">Заказать
    <svg>
      <rect></rect>
    </svg>
  </a>
</div>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: а как можно изменить цвет текста? обычный color:white; не работает

Comment: @Alexander в svg 2 атрибута цвета фигур, для обводки stroke и для заливки fill, я изменил ответ